# Blue Card Renewal

Tags: blue-card

I have applied for Blue card renewal, Immigration office gave me a letter after the appointment stating the law :18b abs 2s.

Will i get blue card or normal residence card, as my previous card was Blue card and it got expired due to expiry of the passport.

Comment: See [18b (2) AufthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0406)

Comment: Thanks for the link.